# Zend framework home page

Tags: linux, apache, zend-framework

I am bit new to Zend frame work(working on LINUX UBUNTU 12.04). Trying to do an initial setup. After I create my domain and setting up ZF structure and when I open my homepage, it is showing a default folder structure something like application, library... etc.

Instead I want to display my index.phtml content sitting in application/views/scripts/index folder. Please help me on how to do that. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the domain pointing to the `./public` directory? Assuming Apache as the web-server, is `mod_rewrite` enabled, thereby pushing all requests through `./public/index.php` ?

Comment: Can you tell me how to check it is pointing to ./public?

And Yes, web server is Apache.

Comment: Are you using online shared hosting? If so, then there are some gotchas: http://www.papayasoft.com/2010/05/08/zend-framework-shared-hosting/ Otherwise, if you are using a local VirtualHost, then the standard Getting Started guides (like https://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/) should give you some direction. Beyond that, your question starts to get the feel of "tell me how do it", not enough "this is what I have tried". StackOverflow is really more a place for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve this issue. By pointing my domain to ./public folder as David suggested.

sudo ln -s   *"...mypublic folder path"*   *"my domain name"*